# how to remove the spell checker in WhatsApp Desktop

Tags: spell-check, whatsapp

On my newly installed laptop with Windows 10, I would like to get rid of the spell checker in WhatsApp **Desktop** software.
How can I do that?

Comment: I would love to know _where_ that is coming from. I mean, which software is responsible for the spell check inside WhatsApp. I don't think it's WhatsApp itself, I see several references online to it being a Windows setting (but then changing windows Typing settings doesn't work). Maybe Edge or some other viewer that runs as a container inside WhatsApp?

Answer (score 13):

To get rid of the spell checker in WhatsApp Desktop and other apps in Windows 11, go to Windows Settings > Time & language > Typing > Typing Insights > set it to off.

Comment: You lost me after Settings - there is no "Devices" and search for devices or typing comes up with no search results.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My OS is in english but I wanted What's App spell checker to work in spanish. So I had to add the spanish language to Windows and then in the Spelling Windows Options I turned on `Multilingual text suggestions`.

To turn the spelling check off I guess it's just a matter to turn off the options in Windows Settings and then restart WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to disable Windows Typing insights. (But this will stop auto correction in other apps too!)

**Windows 10:**
Go to `Windows settings` > `Devices` > `Typing` > `Typing insights` > Turn off

**Windows 11:**
Go to `Windows settings` > `Time & language` > `Typing` > `Typing insights` > Turn off

Answer (score -1):

Whatsapp desktop, click on settings (lower left corner) general, typing, windows settings link, it jumps directly on windows settings, doesn't matter if is windows 10 or 11